# JBOSS AS 7 : ClassNotFoundException: javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactorySpi

Tags: jboss, bouncycastle, jce

I am running **jboss-as-7.1** on **java 1.6**. The custom login module encrypts using **bouncycastle provider**. However jboss throws this error on startup. (Only at trace log level, mind you). Here is my configuration:

1. Added `bouncycastle` as provider in `java.security` file.
2. Download unlimited strength policy files and put in `lib/security`

I know that `javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactorySpi` is already defined in the **jce.jar** file. But it's not being picked up. Not sure what else to try.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactorySpi from [Module "abc.crypto:main" from local module loader @210a6ae2 (roots: /home/ptest/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/modules)]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining your own JBoss module for BouncyCastle?  It looks as though you are, based on the "abc.crypto:main" line you posted.  I typically see the error you described when I am incorrectly referencing a module in my assembly descriptor, or if the module itself is not configured properly.  I'd start there.